# Does a license I put on my own software apply to me? Can I change the license? (Creative Commons BY-SA 4.0)

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I've licensed a piece of software under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International Public License, but I may not want to allow others to use it for commercial uses in the future, so I'm asking whether or not I can change the license for future versions of the piece of software to other licenses such as the CC-Attribution-NonCommercial 4.0 International Public license.

Comment: So the 'ShareAlike' bit doesn't apply to me because I made the software?

Comment: As an aside, [you probably shouldn't be using a CC license on software](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software). The license you've chosen has essentially the same goals as the GPL. Why not, therefore, use the GPL instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've expressly given away ownership (work for hire, signed an agreement with an organization) you own anything you create.  Licenses are there to *control* how you share that code.  The code's *owner* is free to change the terms of how they share the code at any given time.

As a matter of practicality, and to avoid confusion, I would recommend:

- Changing the version number with the change in license--whether there is any material difference in the project or not.
- Provide ample warning to your users that you are doing this change.

If you haven't even released the code at all, then it is as if you haven't picked a license to begin with.

Comment: Just to clarify, Section 3b of the license/the 'ShareAlike' part of the license does not apply to me because I made the software? Does that mean future versions can be released under a different license?

Comment: You made the software, so you own it. **You** are free to do whatever you want with it.  Everyone else is bound by the terms you provided.